# Partial derivative of independent variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose $z=z(x,y)$. The chain rule states that

$$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{∂z}{∂x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{∂z}{∂y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

I have two questions:

1. If $x$ and $y$ are independent variables, what is $dy/dx$? Is it defined? Is it zero?
2. If it is zero, putting $x$ in place of $t$, we get $dz/dx = ∂z/∂x$. Then why is the partial notation relevant?

Edit : my question is concerned with the case when x and y are not stated to be functions of any other variable t. I just used t to illustrate the chain rule first.

Answer (score 1):

If we let $z=f(x,y)$ and $x=g(t)$ and $y=h(t)$, then the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ can be found once we set move everything to one side of the equal sign so that we have a function that looks like $f(x,y,) = 0$. And it is equal to $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-\partial f / \partial x}{\partial f / \partial y}$$

*This can be proved with implicit differentiation, and is also talked about in the link provided*
But, let's say instead we have $z= f(x,y)$ and $y = h(x)$. In that case, we can find $\frac{dz}{dx}$ as $$\frac{\partial f} {\partial x} + \frac{\partial f} {\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}$$

I would recommend avoiding using the same letter to describe both a variable and a function, such as $z=z(x,y)$, as this doesn't really make sense.
Generally, functions are described using the letters such as $f,g,$ or $h$, but isnt necessarily limited to these.

You can check this link about [the chain rule for multivariable calculus](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx) if you still have questions.

Comment: So if no relation between x and y is stated, dy/dx is zero?

Comment: Also, you stated that y and x are functions of t. So if x changes, that means t has changed. Then that would mean y will change. How come dy/dx is zero then?

Comment: You may have helped me realize a mistake haha. It wouldnt be zero, at least not every time. You would have to manipulate the variables so that $t$ is written in terms of either $x$ or $y$, then substitute over into the other equation. Then you could find it using implicit differentiation.

Comment: Indeed :) And what about my first query?

Comment: In fact I think there is a theorem about finding $dy/dx$ from partials, but it's been over a year since I last took multivariable so sadly I don't remember and I don't have my notes at hand

Comment: I edited my answer, should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your post shows $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, and these two are function of $t$. Without relation between $x$ and $y$ which make $z$, these variables are related with $t$, Those are $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$. If you delete $t$ between them you have a function of $y$ respect to $x$. Anyway it's simple to see
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}=\dfrac{y_t}{x_t}$$
Note that when we define a function of two variables, we say $x$ and $y$ act independently, but as a special case, we say $x$ and $y$ can relate with variable $t$.

Comment: I've edited my post for clarity.